# singleton and lockers (mutex)

Tags: java, singleton, mutex

I have a singleton class.
one of his methods is:

```
public static void printMessage(boolean print, String text) {
    if (print) {
        System.out.print(text);
    }
}
```

I have a multithreaded application, and more than one thread are using this method.
I'm not sure, but do I need to add mutex to the implementation of printMessage ?
I think that I dont need to, because I'm not using any class member. Am I right ?

Comment: There really isn't much info in your question.From the look of this one method, I don't see a reason why you would need a "mutex" around anything

Comment: @user3668129 you are right, no need to add locks here. But you should document your method as in future some one can put class member inside this.

Comment: As per open JDK source code println() method is thread safe. while print() method is not.
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.println%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

It's a static method which only uses parameters.  One of the parameters is primitive and the other is immutable.  I don't see a reason to synchronizing the method.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, you are not accessing any shared storage such as member variables, static fields, etc. **However**, you also need to look at any functions you call. Are they thread-safe? In your case, is `System.out.print` thread-safe? If it is not, then two calls such as:

```
//Thread 1
printMessage(true, "abc");

// Thread 2
printMessage(true, "def");
```

might print:

```
adebcf
```

because of interleaving.

Now, the Javadoc for [`print`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.String%29) makes no mention of thread safety. Hence, assume that it is *not* thread-safe.

It is up to you to decide whether text interleaving is a problem for your use case. If so, then take proper precautions to prevent interleaving of print output.